# Creating UIViewController Category (Obj-C) similar to Extension Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, objective-c-category

I'm trying to extend standard `UIViewController` with some custom methods.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController (UIViewControllerExtension)
- (void) showNoHandlerAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title andMessage:     (NSString*)message;
- (void) showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title andMessage:(NSString*)message  buttonTitles:(NSArray<NSString *>*)titles andHandler:(void (^)(UIAlertAction * action))handler;
@end
```

How can I use extended `UIViewController` now? I need to inherit my custom view controllers from extended `UIViewController`.

Comment: put your code here not image of code

Comment: That's a Category, right? Then, just import the .h file on a UIViewController subclassed object.

Comment: Importing .h file to my custom view controller doesn't work. Extension methods are not available.

Answer (score 4):

Create a file "UIViewController+Alert.h" containing:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIViewController (AlertExtension)
- (void) showNoHandlerAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title andMessage:     (NSString*)message;
- (void) showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title andMessage:(NSString*)message  buttonTitles:(NSArray<NSString *>*)titles andHandler:(void (^)(UIAlertAction * action))handler;
@end
```

Then, create a file "UIViewController+Alert.m" that contains:

```
#import "UIViewController+Alert.h"
@implementation UIViewController (AlertExtension)
- (void) showNoHandlerAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title andMessage:     (NSString*)message {
    // Insert code here
}

- (void) showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title andMessage:(NSString*)message  buttonTitles:(NSArray<NSString *>*)titles andHandler:(void (^)(UIAlertAction * action))handler {
    // Insert code here
}
@end
```

In say your "SampleViewController.h":

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SampleViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

Then in "SampleViewController.m":

```
#import "SampleViewController.h"
#import "UIViewController+Alert.h"

@implementation SampleViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self showNoHandlerAlertWithTitle:@"Hello" andMessage:@"World"];
}
@end
```

Comment: It would be enough to import `UIViewController+Alert.h` in the implementation, otherwise you are polluting your headers. Also `@import UIKit;` should be preferred now over `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`.

Comment: Without more context as to which version of Xcode and whether "Enable Modules" is set to YES in his build settings, using @import UIKit; may actually cause his code to not compile; I preferred to heir on the side of caution and re-use similar syntax as used in the question.  That being said, you are quite correct for importing the UIViewController+Alert.h only in the implementation, unless it is your intent for other parts of your code to be able to use these functions on your view controller too!